# When declaring a float range (0, 10.0] what do i have to watch out for?

Tags: floating-point, ada, floating-accuracy

I want this type to only contain values x for which is `(x > 0) && (x <= 10.0)` is true

I declared my type `larger_than_zero` this way:

```
type a_float is digits 6 range - 1.0E38 .. 1.0E38;
type larger_than_zero is new a_float range a_float'Adjacent(0.0, 1.0) .. 10.0;
```

It is now impossible to assign `0.0` to a variable of type `larger_than_zero`.

`'Adjacent(A, B)` takes the next possible machine value starting from `A` that is not `A`, and lies in the direction to `B`

My question is whether this can cause some weird behaviour that would normally not be expected of a type.
Maybe `larger_than_zero'First` isn't even part of the model of `larger_than_zero`?
Any pointers to detailed information on this topic would be appeciated.

Answer (score 3):

It shouldn't cause any problems.  Technically, the `range` declaration on the `type` doesn't have any effect on the *type* at all; it only impacts the *first subtype*.  Your `type larger_than_zero` declaration defines both a type and a first subtype.  The type includes every floating-point number representable in the floating-point format, including negative numbers, zero, and numbers greater than 10.0.  The *first subtype* is a subrange of that type that includes only the numbers you specify in the range.  Calculations are performed using the type, and intermediate results may go outside the range.  The subtype is relevant only for constraint checking; when assigning a `larger_than_zero` variable, or passing a `larger_than_zero` parameter, the value will be checked to make sure it's in range, and `Constraint_Error` will be raised if not.  Since that's really the only use of the range, it shouldn't cause any weird behavior.

One thing to note is that `a_float'Adjacent(0.0, 1.0)` may not return the same thing in different implementations, even if IEEE floats are used in both cases, since some implementations may not support denormalized numbers.  It should be the same, as long as `a_float'Denorm` returns the same value (see A.5.3(10)).  Of course, if one of the implementations is on a machine that doesn't use IEEE floats, such as VAXes, the value of `'Adajcent` could be different.  And, of course, `z_float'Adjacent(0.0, 1.0)`, where `z_float` is an IEEE 64-bit float, will be different from the `a_float` version assuming `a_float` is a 32-bit float.

Comment: ok, so for subtypes this is well defined. what if larger_than_zero would be declared like so: `type larger_than_zero is digits 6 range a_float'Adjacent(0.0, 1.0) .. 10.0`?

Comment: @ker This will work if `a_float` and `larger_than_zero` will have the same representation (i.e. both 32-bit IEEE floats or both 64-bit).  The `type` declaration is equivalent to `type anonymous is digits 6; subtype larger_than_zero is anonymous range ...`, but you can't say `anonymous'Adjacent`, of course.